# android : changing gmail-api scopes

Tags: android, scope, gmail-api

How to change the scope of a application for gmail-api . I had added 
`https://mail.google.com/`, 
`GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS`,
`GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT`,
`GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY`,
`GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE`.

So while adding a gmail account to my app it shows this app can "Modify, manage drafts, send emails and insert in to mail box"

Now i changed the scope to only `GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS`, generated a new APK  and while trying to add a gmail account it still shows the old permissions. So it looks like its getting stored somewhere and is not getting cleared. How can I change i.e. add / delete the scopes?

```
 mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            context, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(email)
    ;
    new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
```

Comment: Can you post your code regarding the scope implementation?